# WebTestClient check jsonPath against another jsonPath

Tags: java, junit, spring-webflux

I have this "content" response from which I need to assert some values.

```
WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec content = response.expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.path1").isEqualTo(value1);
```

If I want to assert some JSON paths with predefined values all is good.

But the tricky part comes when I wanna check if a JSON path is equal to another JSON path.

```
JsonPathAssertions jsonPath2 = bodyContentSpec.jsonPath("$.path2");
JsonPathAssertions jsonPath3 = bodyContentSpec.jsonPath("$.path3");
```

So my question is how can I assert the content of `jsonPath2` against `jsonPath3` using `org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThanOrEqualTo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use the `value(Consumer)` method:

for simple operations:

```java
jsonPath2.value(v->jsonPath3.isEqualTo(v));
```

for using special Matchers:

```java
jsonPath2.value(v->jsonPath3.value(Matchers.greaterThanOrEqualTo(v)));
```

Comment: instead of isEqualTo i need to use org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThanOrEqualTo
can you please post an example using that